# Как получить SSL сертификат используя LetsEncrypt и nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, letsencrypt

Как получить SSL сертификат используя [LetsEncrypt](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%E2%80%99s_Encrypt) и [nginx](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx)?

<sub><sub>вопрос нисколько не претендует на полноту или новизну и создан скорее как напоминалка для автора</sub></sub>

Answer (score 0):

1. Предполагается, что в файле `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` в блоке `server { ... }` есть строчка `include sites-enabled/*;`
2. Создаём папку, в которую letsencrypt запишет временные данные для аутентификации:

   ```
   mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/mock
   ```
3. Создаём файл `/etc/nginx/sites-enables/mock.conf` с содержимым:

   ```
   server {
           listen 80 default_server;
           root /usr/share/nginx/mock;
   }
   ```
4. Получаем сертификат:

   ```
   certbot certonly --email EMAIL --nginx -w /usr/share/nginx/mock -d DOMAIN
   ```
5. Теперь можно убрать `mock.conf` до следующего раза:

   ```
   mv /etc/nginx/sites-available/mock.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
   ```